# SMS not Sending to Customers from Observer.php

Tags: php, api, magento, sms, alert

I need to send **SMS** (By using any SMS API) to customers when products are back in stock.

I have rewrite **Mage_ProductAlert_Model_Observer** class and added SMS API in my **Custom Module**'s Observer.php file but its not sending SMS to customers. Why?

Also, its only showing two customers details instead of all customers subscribed to product stock alert. Here is my code

**Observer.php**

```
    <?php

    class My_Alert_Model_ProductAlert_Observer
    {


        public function process()
        {

        $customer_stock_alerts = Mage::getModel('productalert/stock')
                            ->getCollection()
                            ->addStatusFilter(0)
                            ->setCustomerOrder();

        foreach ($customer_stock_alerts as $alert){

          $stock_back_product = $alert->getProductId();
          $current_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($stock_back_product);
          $current_product_name = $current_product->getName();

          $customer_info = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($alert->getCustomerId());
          $customer_name = $customer_info->getPrimaryBillingAddress()->getFirstname();
          $customer_mobile = $customer_info->getPrimaryBillingAddress()->getTelephone(); 

                $message = 0;


                $message = "Dear $customer_name, Product $current_product_name  is back in Stock";

                $message=urlencode($message);


$sendsms = "http://api.msg91.com/api/sendhttp.php?sender=MSGIND&route=4&mobiles=$customer_mobile&authkey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&country=91&message=$message";


               file_get_contents($sendsms);     
        }


        }

        }

        ?>
```

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
<My_Alert>
<version>0.0.1</version>
</My_Alert>
</modules>
<global>
  <models>
    <my_alert>
      <class>My_Alert_Model</class>
    </my_alert>
  </models>
</global>
    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <my_alert>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr>*/5 * * * *</cron_expr>
                </schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>my_alert_productalert/observer::process</model>
                </run>
            </my_alert>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <My_Alert_First>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>My_Alert</module>
                    <frontName>my-alert</frontName>
                </args>
            </My_Alert_First>
        </routers>
    </frontend>    
</config>
```

Can anyone share what's the issue this & why SMS is not sending?
I'm using Magento 1.9.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento approach to handling Product Stock Alert collection. Our client has more than 40.000 subscribers and more than 30.000 are waiting for status to be changed from “Out of Stock” to “In Stock”. So when Magento tries to load 40.000 records from table product_alert_stock to collection to foreach them because of memory limitation php fails.

I Think you have not change core files you can over ride using your extension this [link](http://inchoo.net/magento/product-stock-alerts-not-working/) help you.

Comment: Yes, I have created my custom module. Please check my updated question. But still SMS is not sending to customers. Why?

Comment: can you check this table product_alert_stock how much record in this?

Comment: Yes, records are there. Also I have already set shortest cron time for every five minutes and its working fine. So confirmed that product alert mails are sending to customers without any issues. But only thing is SMS is not sending. Why?

Comment: No, I have tested directly and its working fine. Can you check my module above?

Comment: is it get mobile number for all $customer_mobile?

Comment: Yes, I have used foreach. For your information I have tried with directly giving my mobile number for testing. But no luck.

Comment: you can write like this
 $sendsms = "http://api.msg91.com/api/sendhttp.php?sender=MSGIND&route=4&mobiles=".$customer_mobile."&authkey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&country=91&message=".$message;

Comment: Yes, I have tried this as well bu not working. You can check this improved question here : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/210910/sms-not-sending-to-customers-from-observer-php

Comment: can you send me api details?Can you sample code for send msg through that api

Comment: For your information I have tested the API link directly and its working fine. But its not sending from Observer.php. I think I did little mistake in Product Alert Core class. Can you check this?

Comment: is it call Observer.php? I think it is not  calle that one

Comment: Please check here for whole code : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/210910/sms-not-sending-to-customers-from-observer-php

Comment: have you enable this To set up Magento Product Alerts please go to System > Configuration > Catalog > Product Alerts then select Yes to "Allow Alert When Product Comes Back in Stock" field.

Comment: public function process()
    {
        Mage::log('ProductAlert started @' . now(), false, 'product_alert_workflow.log', true);
 
        $email = Mage::getModel('productalert/email');
        /* @var $email Mage_ProductAlert_Model_Email */
        $this->_processPrice($email);
        $this->_processStock($email);
        $this->_sendErrorEmail();
 
        Mage::log('ProductAlert finished @' . now(), false, 'product_alert_workflow.log', true);
 
        return $this;
    }

Comment: I have already set "Allow Alert When Product Comes Back in Stock" field to Yes. Also added your code in my module's observer.php file. But its not working. Why?

Comment: can you send me zip so i can test my side

Comment: Send your email id to send zip

Comment: jscatoz@gmail.com

Comment: I have added my entire module files here : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/210910/sms-not-sending-to-customers-from-observer-php
So please check it.

Comment: Have you checked this?

Comment: Have you checked this?